# Failed to download symfony/finder from dist: There was an error extracting the ZIP file. Corrupt file?

Tags: php, git, symfony, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to clone a Laravel 4.1 project onto a Vagrant 1.6.3 VM, but when I try to install the composer dependencies by running `composer install` I get the following:

```
  - Installing symfony/finder (2.4.x-dev 4a15fc1)
    Downloading: 100%
Failed to download symfony/finder from dist: There was an error extracting the Z
IP file. Corrupt file?
Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/finder (2.4.x-dev 4a15fc1)
    Cloning 4a15fc12b56ca06d3a6bf32ef8f603ccb421d846



  [RuntimeException]

  Failed to execute git checkout "4a15fc12b56ca06d3a6bf32ef8f603ccb421d846" && g
it reset --hard "4a15fc12b56ca06d3a6bf32ef8f603ccb421d846"
  error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by chec
kout:
        .gitignore

        Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php

        Adapter/AbstractFindAdapter.php

        Adapter/AdapterInterface.php

        Adapter/BsdFindAdapter.php

        Adapter/GnuFindAdapter.php

        Adapter/PhpAdapter.php

        CHANGELOG.md

        Comparator/Comparator.php

        Comparator/DateComparator.php

        Comparator/NumberComparator.php

        Exception/AccessDeniedException.php

        Exception/AdapterFailureException.php

        Exception/ExceptionInterface.php

        Exception/OperationNotPermitedException.php

        Exception/ShellCommandFailureException.php

        Expression/Expression.php

        Expression/Glob.php

        Expression/Regex.php

        Expression/ValueInterface.php

        Finder.php

        Glob.php

        Iterator/CustomFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/DateRangeFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/DepthRangeFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/FilePathsIterator.php

        Iterator/FileTypeFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/FilecontentFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/FilenameFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/FilterIterator.php

        Iterator/MultiplePcreFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/PathFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php

        Iterator/SizeRangeFilterIterator.php

        Iterator/SortableIterator.php

        LICENSE

        README.md

        Shell/Command.php

        Shell/Shell.php

        SplFileInfo.php

        Tests/Comparator/ComparatorTest.php

        Tests/Comparator/DateComparatorTest.php

        Tests/Comparator/NumberComparatorTest.php

        Tests/Expression/ExpressionTest.php

        Tests/Expression/GlobTest.php

        Tests/Expression/RegexTest.php

        Tests/FakeAdapter/DummyAdapter.php

        Tests/FakeAdapter/FailingAdapter.php

        Tests/FakeAdapter/NamedAdapter.php

        Tests/FakeAdapter/UnsupportedAdapter.php

        Tests/FinderTest.php

        Tests/Fixtures/A/B/C/abc.dat

        Tests/Fixtures/A/B/ab.dat

        Tests/Fixtures/A/a.dat

        Tests/Fixtures/copy/A/B/C/abc.dat.copy

        Tests/Fixtures/copy/A/B/ab.dat.copy

        Tests/Fixtures/copy/A/a.dat.copy

        Tests/Fixtures/dolor.txt

        Tests/Fixtures/ipsum.txt

        Tests/Fixtures/lorem.txt

        Tests/Fixtures/one/a

        Tests/Fixtures/one/b/c.neon

        Tests/Fixtures/one/b/d.neon

  Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.

  Aborting



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-p
lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--ver
bose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

I tried some random stuff like clearing my .gitignore file and deleting the vendor/syfony/Finder directory (which it seems to be failing on) but no luck. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug introduced today for Windows users (Vagrant on Windows too). I reported it and fix is in the way: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11984.

A file was committed a file a folder named r+e.g?e*x[c]a(r)s which contains a number of characters that are invalid (specifically * and ?) on NTFS filesystems. Until it is reverted, that package is broken as well as any that require it as a dependency.

**A PR was merged and it should be now fixed.**